# Select a specific column in SQL Server from a concatenation from a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to select a specific column based off a value in another table

I have one table with the following columns:

`TableA`:

```
Item_Id,Column01,Column02,Column03,Column04,Column05,
```

Sample data for `TableA` respectively:

```
1,$1.00,$2.00,$3.00,$4.00,$5.00
```

`TableB` columns:

```
 Item_ID,Column
```

Data for `TableB`:

```
1,05
```

I want to be able to return the value based on what I have in `TableB`. Currently I'm concatenating to get the field name, but I don't know how to get the value.

```
Select 'Column'+TableB.[Column] 
from TableA 
inner join TableB on TableA.Item_Id = TableB.ItemB
WHERE TableA.Item_Id = 1
```

So for this particular example the query would select column05 from `TableA` and the result would be $5.00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CASE statament

```
Select CASE TableB.[Column] When '01' THEN TableA.Column01
                            When '02' THEN TableA.Column02
                            When '03' THEN TableA.Column03
                            When '04' THEN TableA.Column04
                            When '05' THEN TableA.Column05
       END as Value
from TableA 
inner join TableB on TableA.Item_Id = TableB.ItemB
WHERE TableA.Item_Id = 1
```

But the column01 ... column05 of tableA need to be of the same data type, or converted to the same data type.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure why I was trying to make this harder than it needed to be.